# Visual Studio Lightswitch, create a search parameter that auto updates browse screen?

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2013, lightswitch-2013

done a bit of research and not found anything for this... I have created a LightSwitch application for a basic contacts table.. the Browse sceen contains the name, number etc... when im using the search parameter, is it possible or this search text box to auto refresh after each key stroke?

for example I type in 'A', and based on the surname it loads all surnames that begins with an A, and without pressing the enter key.

can this be done with internal settings? or am I required to use JavaScript or C#> thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this from http://blog.pragmaswitch.com/?p=1670, and it works beautifully. I use it in all my search screens.

```
myapp.BrowseScreen.SearchText_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    // This block is from somewhere else, sets the focus to the search box
    $searchBox = $("input", $(element));
    setTimeout(function () {
        $searchBox.focus();
    }, 1);

    // The blog post linked above set the required characters to 3, but I liked the instant filtering of 1
    onInputAsYouType(element, 1, function (text) {
        contentItem.screen.SearchText = text; //SearchText here is the data item in the screen designer linked to the query parameter
    });

    function onInputAsYouType(element, numberOfRequiredChars, done) {
        var inputbox = $("input", $(element));
        inputbox.on("input", function (e) {
            var text = $(this).val();
            if (text.length >= numberOfRequiredChars)
                done(text);
        });
    };
};
```

You can go to the blog post for screenshots, but it's pretty straightforward. Create your browse / search screen, make the search text a text box, and plug this code into the post render.

Comment: By the way, this solution is for an HTML Client.

Comment: have you ever tried to get this working on a text area? ive discovered a bug on a android devices, where unless you tap off the text box, then data is not saved, however if I enter the above code on a text box, then the "text" box can be passed to a global parameter on the screen, and therefore be saved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code, but you may try to insert your code directly in the "text_changed" event of your textBox.

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your code here for instance, or call a method that contain your code
    }
```

Comment: ive not done any code yet, I was just wondering if it was possible, i saw a function in javascript with keypress but im not sure of how i link it upto the search parameter textbox ive created (called search)

Comment: I'm not very experienced with JS sorry, but I think it's possible to do it simply using C# on VS 2013

Comment: how would you do it on c# if you dont mind me asking

Comment: I don't really know cause I don't really understand your project.. Where should the textbox search (database, list...)

Comment: its hard to explain really, basically ive created a table called contacts in sql server, connected it to visual studio lightswitch, and from the table view, you can insert c# however its on the actual screen view where ive created the parameter which is done using java script.... ill have to keep looking into it, cheers for the help

Comment: hmmm hard to understand too ^^ You may search on the web "using textbox as search bar c#" or something like that, as I told you, I don't really know JS..